# Parallel Iterating in FOR EACH Loop

Tags: java, performance, optimization, data-structures

I want to optimise my code, and for that, I want to iterate parallely through Maps.

My current code is:

```
for (String orderKey: insertMap.keySet()) {
    if(orderKey.contains('#New')) {
        //Do big stuff: (500 lines)
    }
}

for (String orderKey: updateMap.keySet()) {
    if(orderKey.contains('#New')) {
        //Do same big stuff as above: (500 lines)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding the types of Map

```
Map<String,CustomObject> insertMap,updateMap = new Map<String,CustomObject>();
```

Now, as you can see, then inner `IF` condition is same, only the values of the `orderKey`are coming from different maps.

The values of the `orderKey` will be different from each Map. They won't ever be the same.

Is there a way to combine these `FOR` Loops in one?
Maybe like :

```
for((String orderKey : insertMap.keySet()) OR (String orderKey : udpateMap.keySet()))
{
    if(orderKey.contains('#New')) {
        //Do big stuff
    }
}
```

I know the above code is not possible, I just wanted to show what I am looking for.

The number of lines that I have masked by the `//Do Big Stuff` are almost 500. And hence I want to reduce the lines of code.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: move //Do big stuff: (500 lines) in a method and call it there. if there are some over lapping step move them in one method and keep different steps in different methods and call both of them in the if's

Comment: What are the types of the values here?  Please update your code and your question to include 1) the type declaration of both insertMap and updateMap  2) clarify whether the two maps will contain the same keys 3) if both maps contain the same key, should `Do big stuff` run once or twice for the values in each of those maps?

Comment: @whaley Hi, I have added the required editing. Two maps will not contain the same keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use [`Stream.concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-):

```
Stream.concat(insertMap.keySet().stream(), updateMap.keySet().stream())
    .filter(orderKey -> orderKey.contains("#New"))
    .forEach(orderKey -> {
        ...
    });
```

Google's [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has [`Iterables.concat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)):

```
for (String orderKey: Iterables.concat(insertMap.keySet(), updateMap.keySet())) {
    ...
}
```

And of course, the most "low tech" way would be to simply extract a method:

```
for (String orderKey: insertMap.keySet()) {
    if (orderKey.contains("#New")) {
        doBigStuff(orderKey);
    }
}

for (String orderKey: updateMap.keySet()) {
    if (orderKey.contains("#New")) {
        doBigStuff(orderKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually using this code in Salesforce Apex, hence I can't use custom libraries!

Comment: Thanks. I will have to check whether Apex supports Java 8 features. If it does, then this will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want parallelism, first extract you doStuff(key) function to a class that implements Runnable interface.
Then  define a thread pool executor with as many threads as you need. Your for loops may remain, but instead of calling your function, create an instance of you new class and submit to your executor.